# Objective C: Do I need to release the NSString in this example?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
debugTestLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g, %g", @"Testing String", @"I am another"];
```

I alloc the String and immediately assign to the text, but I don't know whether the string can auto release or not.

Answer (score 4):

No it will not autorelease, you have to release it. If you used [NSString stringWithFormat], however, it would autorelease.

Comment: really? that's rather nice.  typically not described anywhere I've seen either (and should be)

Comment: @kevindtimm it is described in the SDK documentation. Check it out sometime, all sorts of other goodies in there.

Comment: Um, I haven't seen this documented either, but lotsa experience says that class method [XXX XXXWithYYY] would normally return an autoreleasing object. Early on in my iPhone project, I encountered and debugged some overrelease bugs with those...

Comment: The convention is that methods beginning "alloc" or "new" or containing "copy" return an object you need to release; other method names return autoreleased objects. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev how did you miss it? Did you never read the SDK documentation? It is right there in the documentation for NSString: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW13

Comment: @freespace: I've never seen a general statement about [Foo FooWithBar] documented. It's probably in the memory management guide somewhere...

Comment: @freespace - the term 'autorelease' is referenced in your link in 3 places, none of those are stringWithFormat - hence the 'surprise'

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. It isn't that you didn't know about `stringWithFormat`. It is that you didn't know it returns an autorelease object. This is documented in http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011 with a specific example at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447 Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

jupp, add `autorelease` to the end

Answer (score 1):

yes, alloc == release (an easy rule to remember)

Comment: Also copy. And you have to watch for every instance of giving the ref away. I wish it was that simple...

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW6), you will find the `text` property is copied - there is no need for you to keep that `NSString` instance around.

So the answer is yes: you can (auto)release that `NSString` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends.

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:...];
```

This will construct a string with retain count of +1. If the `text` property is `@property(retain)` or `@property(copy)`, then the `debugTestLabel` will adopt its ownership, so you should `-release` (or `-autorelease`) it afterwards.

However, if the `text` property is `@property(assign)`, then the `debugTestLabel` doesn't claim ownership, and you have to make sure the text lives longer than the label uses it.

(If the label is a `UILabel` subclass then it's the first case.)

Answer (score 0):

The rule is, if the method starts with `init` you have to `release` (or `autorelease` it). Otherwise it's an autoreleased object (`stringWithFormat:` for example). So in this case you should change the code to:

```
debugTestLabel.text = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g, %g", @"Testing String", @"I am another"] autorelease];
```

or more standard,

```
debugTestLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g, %g", @"Testing String", @"I am another"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should release the string immediately after the use of the string.